# how to execute shell command with arguments?

Tags: c#, .net, shell, command, arguments

I`m trying to execute a shell command with arguments in C# , and "***The system cannot find the file specified***" is thrown.

I`ve tried:

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\timesync\\NistClock.exe sync";
```

the path is correct 100% NistClock.exe gets executed when is run without the parameter "sync"

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "c#". That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should change a little bit your code:

```
p.StartupInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "timesync\\NistClock.exe");
p.StartupInfo.Arguments = "sync";
```

Answer (score 5):

```
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\timesync\\NistClock.exe";                
string args = "sync";
ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo(path, args);
Process process = Process.Start(p);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`Arguments`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments) property.

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\timesync\\NistClock.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "sync";
```

By the way, be careful about using `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`.  Note that this method can return something different if you're using any file dialogs throughout your application.  It might be a better option to use something like `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` instead, and parse the directory from there.